# Photon number distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-optics, wigner-transform

Is there any relationship to write the "photon number distribution" in terms of "Wigner's function"? I have a wavefunction for a specific quantum system and I have calculated corresponding ground state vector and Wigner's function.

Comment: Hint: it is a convolution of Hermite polynomials and Gaussians, as @Emilio_Pisanty tells you below, but it amounts to a Gaussian times a well-known expression for that convolution, a Laguerre polynomial.

Comment: @Cosmas That's the $g(x,p)$, right? Because OP hasn't actually said what the ground state actually is.

Comment: @Emilio Yes, your last integral... I assume his text does the oscillator, so it is a matter of recognizing the convolved bilinear of Hermites....

Comment: @Cosmas Yeah, that integral definitely looks like a job for [the DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/18.17.E48), though I imagine Gradshteyn & Ryzhik and Prudnikov et al. also have that in there.

Comment: Oh, I would assume his book would replicate the original [Groenewold](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/soysoy/20Groenewold46.pdf), (5.14) to (5.16) via (5.13) ... but note he slips into Legendre when he really means Laguerre!!! All L-French names being the same!!!

Comment: @Emilio Of course, in our book we do it trivially from first principles... We never have to consider Hermites... it is *all* Laguerres... That's the power of the * that HG discovered. But I'm digressing....

Comment: In his book, Schleich has the integral explicitly on p 106.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Sounds interesting, I'd chase it up if I had time. OP doesn't seem all that interested, though.

Comment: Anyway, the pros use the respective [generating functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/18.12#E13) 18.12.13,15,16  ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can calculate the expectation value of any observable $\hat G$ in terms of the Wigner function $W(x,p)$: if
$$
 W(x,p)~\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}~\frac{1}{\pi\hbar}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi^*(x+y)\psi(x-y)e^{2ipy/\hbar}\,dy\,
$$
(as in e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution)) then
$$
\displaystyle \langle \psi |{\hat {G}}|\psi \rangle =Tr({\hat {\rho }}{\hat {G}})=\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }dx\,\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }dp W(x,p)g(x,p) 
$$
where
$$
g(x,p)\equiv\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\, \langle x-y/2| \hat{G} |x+y/2 \rangle e^{ipy/\hbar}.
$$
For the photon-number distribution $p_n=\langle\psi|n\rangle\langle n|\psi\rangle$, you just take $\hat G = |n\rangle\langle n|$ and calculate.